# can someone pls explain what the given argument is in randint

Tags: python

hi can someone pls explain what the given argument is when I run

```
import random
random.randint()
```

and get this result

```
TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

and also explain in what other situations this occurs

Thanks

Comment: `randint` is not a built-in function and, based on your error, does not appear to be the one from the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) library; what `randint` function are you trying to call?

Comment: Also I'd recommend just doing a `help(randint)` to see the documentation.

Comment: I just don't understand what the (1 given) is I know I haven't used it correctly

Comment: Well, ```randint``` is a class and functions in classes will add a ```self``` argument its self

Comment: Yes, I am saying the one argument is ```self```

Comment: can you explain the need for self pls I'm new to this

Comment: We really need more information here. Our guessing game took us so far, but the problem as it is is not reproducible. When I run a program with no other code than `randint()` I (and everyone else) will get `NameError: name 'randint' is not defined`. Please give us a minimal code example that produces this error.

Comment: sorry i put the whole thing in now

Comment: Now the error should be `TypeError: randint() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'`. Please add the Python version you're using and add a `print(random.__file__)` before you try to call the function. You might have overwritten the `random` module from the standard library.

Comment: I'm using version 2.7.10

Comment: OK. [Python 2.7 was released in 2010 and the whole Python 2 branch is dead since the beginning of 2020](https://devguide.python.org/devcycle/#end-of-life-branches). You seem to be a beginner so why don't you use Python 3? You might find more help if you don't use an outdated and not longer supported version of the language.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this:

```
from random import randint
print(randint(1, 10)) # creates a random number from 1 to 10
```

Comment: According to the error message in the question we're talking about a different `randint` function here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
r = random.randint(a, b)
```

The function requires two parameters, where the returned integer is of a <= X <= b